# How can I request data with device access code for default gateway router 5268AC?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, network-programming

I would like to write a script that can collect data from the router, in this case 5268AC. So far, I've been able to use `response.get()` to get information from URLs that do not require device access code to see information. To get information about Wifi, for example, the default SSID, I need to enter the access code located on the router via the browser. I keep getting error 500 when trying `request.post(url)`.

url="http://192.168.1.254/xslt?PAGE=C_2_1"

From inspection, I believe this is the form I'm trying fill. The key value is `ADM_PASSWORD`.

```
              <h2>Login</h2>
              <p>Device access code required. Please enter the device access code, then click Submit.</p>
              <form name="pagepost" method="post" action="xslt?PAGE=login_post" id="pagepost">
                <input type="hidden" name="NONCE" value="0abc59f54121398" />
                <input type="hidden" name="THISPAGE" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="NEXTPAGE" value="C_2_1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="CMSKICK" value="" />
                <div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ADM_PASSWORD">Access code</label>
                    <span>
                      <input type="password" id="ADM_PASSWORD" name="ADM_PASSWORD" size="16" maxlength="16" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p align="right">
                  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
```

I tried this but got 500 status error.

```
payload = { 'ADM_PASSWORD':'*access code*' }
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Is there a way to be able to collect information via requests instead of using GUI?

Comment: you have to send all values in `payload` - even `hidden` and `submit`. And url in `action` is relative - so if you display page i.e. `http://192.168.1.254/login` then full address is `http://192.168.1.254/login/xslt?PAGE=login_post`

Comment: you use url with  `PAGE=C_2_1`  but in form you have `PAGE=login_post` (in `action`) and this value you should use in url in `post()`

Comment: in `Chrome`/`Firefox` you can use `DevTools` (tab: `Network`) to see what browser sends when you login.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added all the values like you said into the payload. I also found out that the headers `Content-type:` in the `Network` tab is different for the `POST` since it is a form. It worked after fixing these issues

Comment: @furas could you write that as an answer and then nkone can mark it as the best answer :) this will help other users who get the same issue :)

Comment: if you use `data=` or `json=` then it should set automatically set also correct `Content-Type` and `Content-Length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in `Chrome`/`Firefox` you can use `DevTools` (tab: `Network`) to see what browser sends when you login.

Form has `action="xslt?PAGE=login_post"` so you should send to

```
url = "http://192.168.1.254/xslt?PAGE=login_post"
```

It is relative path - so if you would open page ie. `http://http://192.168.1.254/login/` then it would need

```
url = "http://192.168.1.254/login/xslt?PAGE=login_post"
```

You have to send all `input` which you see in form - especially `hidden`.
Sometimes it may need even `submit`.

And you should use `name=` as key, not `id=`

```
payload = { 
    'NONCE': '0abc59f54121398',
    'THISPAGE': '',
    'NEXTPAGE': 'C_2_1',
    'CMSKICK': '',
    'ADM_PASSWORD': '*access code*' 
}
```

If you use `post()` with `data=` or `json=` then it should automatically set correct value in `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` and you don't have to set it in `headers`.

---

You may also first run `get()` to page with form because it may set cookies which server/device may also check.

---

Problem can be only if page uses JavaScript to generate some extra data in `form` and it would need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) - but it would need to write all with `Selenium`

---

Sometimes I send request to `https://httpbin.org/post` and it sends me back all headers, cookies, post data which it get from me and I can compare it with data which I see in `DevTools`.

Evetually I use local proxy server [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and use it in browser and in Python to see if code sends the same data as browser.